# Implement WebSocket and LWSWS servers in same executable with libwebsockets

Tags: libwebsockets

I'm trying to create a Web Socket server and a `LWSWS` web server provided in `libwebsockets v2.0`.

I just need a simple web server to provide HTML/JS/CSS content to the browser and a web sockets server to work with the Web front-end.

The only doc available is really short and doesn't say anything about that, as v2.0 is brand new. The **libwebsockets GitHub** recommand to refer to the `LWSWS` example in the project, but the procedures to implement and run a server for `LWSWS` and a Web Socket server are not matching (the first using **libuv event loop**, the other using **built-in libwebsockets functions**).

Maybe the only solution is implementing my own *http callback* but I want to make sure that there's no faster solution using `LWSWS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to compile and run a `LWSWS` server from **libwebsockets**, embedding an *HTTP Server* and a *Web Socket server* in the same executable.

### Guidelines

1. Use code from example **lwsws/main.c**, and copy **.h** and **.c** depencies to compile an `LWSWS` server
2. Use code from example **plugin-standalone/protocol_example_standalone.c** to compile your **protocol plugin .dll**
3. Create a quick server and vhost configuration from **lwsws/etc-lwsws-conf.d-localhost-EXAMPLE** and **lwsws/etc-lwsws-conf-EXAMPLE**
4. Put compiled plugins and libs at the right spot and enjoy your server

In case it might help !